# Use status bar for commands (ie. :s or :g) in gVim

Tags: vim, statusbar

I'm not sure if this is the default behavior, but when I open multiple windows, I get multiple status bars (see below). This is ideal when I have multiple windows open. However, when I try to search, or issue a command, it goes all the way down to the bottom (see below). Is there any way to force it to show in, over or under the status bar of each window?

[image: status bars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing status-line and command-line. Type:

```
:help status-line
```

and:

```
:help command-line`
```

There's no way to move command-line somewhere else, unfortunately, nor combine these two. You can even turn the status line for "last" window (the bottom ones) by using:

```
:set laststatus=0
```

just to emphasize the difference.

Comment: I wasn't confusing it, but I didn't know what the command-line was called.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to show the command line anywhere but at the bottom.

The statuslines can be modified in that way that you can turn them off completely, all of them (the `laststatus` option modifies this), have them show only when there are at least two windows open (`laststatus=1` behaviour, the one you have), or have them show all the time for all windows (`laststatus=2`).

One last thing ... regardless of where it is, the command line (at the bottom) issues buffer specific commands to the active buffer (the one with the green statusline), so there really isn't a need for let's say, four of them ...

Comment: I didn't one four per se, I just wanted it to be as close to the main window as possible